# Cognos Report Studio Prompt Mysterious check marks

Tags: prompt, cognos

Hi has anyone encountered this mysterious prompt check marks?
I created the prompt page as normal, and sometimes it acts weird (see link for screenshot). I only click on one prompt, but many mysterious check marks appear, and no consistency on what congos sees as input.

Cognos 10.2.1
Report Studio

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7d5ghkmvll2mc8w/cap.png?dl=0

Comment: Looks like a browser rendering issue to me.  What browser have you been using?  Have you experienced it across multiple browsers?  Do you see then when you're running Report Studio, or when you're running the actual report?  IMX, 10.2.1 performs best on Firefox.

Comment: Thanks Bacon! I've been using IE, and the problem fixed itself when i switched to Firefox.